# Set line height to text inside a variable

Tags: php, html, css

I have a variable, inside there's a long sentence:

```
$myvar = 'i am a quite long sentence, more than 500 chars';
```

With css, I echo it, and I get 3 lines of text.

```
echo '<p>'.$myvar.'</p>';
```

How do I set css line height to it, cause it seems when I echo the query my `line-height` of `12px` is ignored.

Any ideas?
Not sure I was very clear with my q.

**P.S. Yes, didn't know how to explain :). Sorry... The variable gets it's value from an xml field... and, how can i explain, its echo'ed like a big chunk of teext, ignoring the styles**

Comment: What do you mean by "when I echo the query my `line-height` of `12px` is ignored"? Where do you set `line-height`? BTW, you `echo` your variable using PHP, not using CSS.

Comment: If you do `echo '<p style="line-height: 12px;">'.$myvar.'</p>';` does it get ignored??

Comment: Yes, didn't know how to explain :). Sorry... The variable gets it's value from an xml field... and, how can i explain, its echo'ed like a big chunk of teext, ignoring the styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to set the line-height, the easiest way is

```
echo '<p style="line-height:12px">'.$myVar.'</p>';
```

A more elegant way would be to define a class or set for all your paragraph tags a line-height.

**I. css global line-height for all paragraph tags**

```
p {line-height: 12px}
```

**II. css file with class for line height**

```
p.foo {line-height: 12px}
```

**corresponding php code**

```
echo '<p class="foo">'.$myVar.'</p>';
```

Comment: If @thirtydot has already set `line-height` somewhere and it's not working, it might be due to `$myvar` having unescaped characters. So `htmlspecialchars($myvar)` might help too.

Comment: @Nithin Philips: I'm not the person who asked the question.

Comment: Oops. Sorry. Should've paid more attention :D